# Convert Dictionary<string, object> to class and subclass

Tags: c#, dictionary

How do I convert a Dictionary to class and subclasses recursively?
These are my classes:

```
public class UiItem
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public Rect rect { get; set; } 
}

public class Rect
{
    public int height { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int y { get; set; }
    public int x { get; set; }
}
```

I wrote this, but i don't know how create object `Rect` in class `UiItem`:

```
public static T GetObject<T>(this Dictionary<string, object> dict)
    {
        Type type = typeof(T);
        var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

        foreach (var kv in dict)
        {
            var prop = type.GetProperty(kv.Key);
            object value = kv.Value;
            if (kv.Value.GetType() == typeof(Dictionary<string, object>))
            {
                value = GetObject<_???_>((Dictionary<string, object>) value) // <= This line
            }

            if(prop == null) continue;
            prop.SetValue(obj, value, null);
        }
        return (T)obj;
    }
```

Comment: Is your object structure `n` levels deep? If it's only 2 levels deep why not take 2 type parameters?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to pass the type as a parameter rather than using a generic method.  This is then:

```
public static Object GetObject(this Dictionary<string, object> dict, Type type)
    {
        var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

        foreach (var kv in dict)
        {
            var prop = type.GetProperty(kv.Key);
            if(prop == null) continue;

            object value = kv.Value;
            if (value is Dictionary<string, object>)
            {
                value = GetObject((Dictionary<string, object>) value, prop.PropertyType); // <= This line
            }

            prop.SetValue(obj, value, null);
        }
        return obj;
    }
```

You can then create a generic version that performs the casting:

```
public static T GetObject<T>(this Dictionary<string, object> dict)
{
    return (T)GetObject(dict, typeof(T));
}
```

Comment: This is great! I did have to add some extra code to handle nullability.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by @Dan Bryant s answer, but in my case my dictionaries have ILists properties, so here I leave you how I did it.

```
public static T ToClass<T>(Dictionary<string, object> dict)
{
   return (T)ConverToClass(dict, typeof(T));
}

  
    private static object ConverToClass(Dictionary<string, object> dic, Type classToUse)
    {
        Type type = classToUse;
        var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

        foreach (var item in dic)
        {
            var property = type.GetProperty(item.Key);
            if (property == null) continue;

            var value = item.Value;
            if (value is Dictionary<string, object> && !property.PropertyType.FullName.Contains("Generic.IList"))
            {
                property.SetValue(obj, ConverToClass((Dictionary<string, object>)(item.Value), property.PropertyType));
                continue;
            }
            if (property.PropertyType.FullName.Contains("Generic.IList"))
            {
                var subClassTouse = property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];

                Type genericListType = typeof(List<>);
                Type concreteListType = genericListType.MakeGenericType(subClassTouse);
                var list = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(concreteListType, new object[] { });

                var values = (Dictionary<string, object>)dic[item.Key];

                foreach (var itemClass in values)
                {
                    list.Add(ConverToClass((Dictionary<string, object>)itemClass.Value, subClassTouse));
                }
                property.SetValue(obj, list);
                continue;
            }
            property.SetValue(obj, item.Value);
        }

        return obj;
    }
```